# Looking for SOAP API to Retrieve email form a Content Builder sub-folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, soap-api, content-builder

I can execute a Retrieve filtering by name and return any email in the parent Content Builder folder, but when I attempt to Retrieve using a filter of the ID (Category) of the sub-folder, nothing is returned. If you remove the filter below, it returns all Emails from the root folder.

'
      
         
            Email
            Name
            CreatedDate
            Client.ID
            CustomerKey
            ID
            CategoryID
            
               CategoryID
               equals
               109041
            
          
      
   '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use SOAP and content builder. SOAP only works with the Email Studio which will be sunset in Q1 2019. To interact with Content Builder you have to use [REST APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm)

Comment: I had working SOAP code for sending email... Just found out the only reason it was working was that they had a duplicate email template in Classic witht he exact same name...  Thank you.